# React: useState delay issues

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update state with the result of an await axios function, but the state is out of sync by one cycle. Here is the code...

```
 const Index=() => {
  const [fileSelected, setfileSelected]=useState(null)
  const [uploadId, setuploadId]=useState('')
  const [Fred, setFred]=useState('')
  const [fileName, setfileName]=useState('')
  const [fileType, setfileType]=useState('')
  const [uploadPC, setuploadPC]=useState()
  const [backendUrl, setbackendUrl]=useState('http://localhost:4000')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("inside useEffect: ", Fred);
  }, [Fred]);
  
  const fileHandler=async(e) =>{
    try {
      let fileSelected = document.getElementById('myfile').files[0]
      let fileName = fileSelected.name
      let fileType = fileSelected.type
      setfileSelected(fileSelected)
      setfileName(fileName)
      setfileType(fileType)
      console.log(fileSelected)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err, err.message) 
    }
  }

   const startUpload=async(e) =>{
    try {
      e.preventDefault()
      
      const params = {
        fileName: fileName,
        fileType: fileSelected.type
      };
      
      let resp = await axios.get(`${backendUrl}/start-upload`, { params })
      const { uploadId } = resp.data
      console.log(uploadId)// this is all OK
      setFred(uploadId)
      console.log(Fred)//"This displays the previous cycle: ",
      uploadMultipartFile()
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("startupload ",err)
    }
  }

   const uploadMultipartFile=async() =>{    
    try {
      console.log('Delayed access to the state in here',Fred)
      const fileSize = fileSelected.size
      const CHUNK_SIZE = 5000000 // 5MB
      const CHUNKS_COUNT = Math.floor(fileSize / CHUNK_SIZE) + 1
      let promisesArray = []
      let start, end, blob
      console.log(uploadId)
      for (let index = 1; index < CHUNKS_COUNT + 1; index++) {
        start = (index - 1) * CHUNK_SIZE
        end = (index) * CHUNK_SIZE
        blob = (index < CHUNKS_COUNT) ? fileSelected.slice(start, end) : fileSelected.slice(start)

        let getUploadUrlResp = await axios.get(`${backendUrl}/get-upload-url`, {
          params: {
            fileName: fileName,
            partNumber: index,
            uploadId: Fred,
          }
        })
etc
```

The correct uploadId is not available from within uploadMultipartFile which is causing big problems.

I have heard that I should `useEffect`, but not sure how to at the moment. I am refactoring from a class and that worked OK

Comment: When does the upload starts? Right after the user has selected the file? Or is there a button?

Comment: HI there is a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setFred` is an asynchronous method, so you can't get the updated value of `Fred` immediately after `setFred()`.

```
setFred(uploadId)
console.log(Fred) // This will console old state value of `Fred`
```

You should use `useEffect` with adding a `Fred` dependency to check updated value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(Fred)
  if (Fred) // This means if Fred is not default empty state.
    uploadMultipartFile()
}, [Fred])
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I have already tried this but with no joy. Any other thoughts?

Comment: "no joy"-  what do you mean? can you update your question with your whole react component codebase?

Comment: Thanks @william Wang. I have added more code

Comment: so what is the result of "inside useEffect: " ? you should see it twice

Comment: Thanks. Yes the first time empty and then it is the same as the uploadId which means it has updated, but then when I try and access Fred from within uploadMultipartFile or console log it is empty

Comment: you need to call uploadMultipartFile inside useEffect. let me update.

Comment: Brilliant thanks so much William. I can access state from there now, but that function also calls anotehr function getUploadUrlResp which does not have access to Fred. I have added that function to the code. Do I also have to call that from within useEffect

Comment: no, you don't need to. FYI, you did console.log(uploadId) inside uploadMultipartFile, not console.log(Fred)

Comment: Thanks. Yes that was an old console log before I changed the name to Fred. The reason I asked was that getUploadUrlResp params uploadID is not being set to Fred.

Comment: It should be. what is the result of `console.log('Delayed access to the state in here',Fred)`

Comment: The suggested method might work, but it implements a confusing sequence. This is what it is doing: `updating Fred to re-render and checking from a useEffect if Fred has been updated and then calling uploadMultipartFile() that will see the new Fred value` when you really need this `call uploadMultipartFile(Fred, whatever else this function needs)`.

Comment: I got this working thanks William. I had not removed the uploadMultipartFile() from the main body of the code

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

Can you move `uploadMultipartFile()` out of your component? Let the `setState` calls be made from `startUpload`.

```
const startUpload = async (e) => {
  try {
    // 1 - GATHER NECESSARY PARAMETERS HERE fileName uploadId etc...
    // 2 - CALL await uploadMultipartFile(...necessaryParameters)
    // 3 - SET NECESSARY STATE AFTER SUCCESSFUL UPLOAD
  }
  catch {
    // HANDLE ERRORS FROM UPLOAD CODE
  }
}
```

Could this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to use multipart and also preferably signedUrls as I have big files

Comment: You can do that. The example is just to illustrate the pattern. Update whatever state you need and from the `button` click you'll check if the `state` conditions are met before initiating the upload. I don't think you need `useEffect`.